# Overleaf math writing shorthands

Tags: math, latex, shorthand, overleaf, obsidian

I was using a platform called "Obsidian" to take notes and I downloaded a plugin called "Quick maths" where you could write something like this:

```
$$
al:\alpha;
be:\beta;
ga:\gamma;
$$
```

and if you were working on a .tex using math or equation enviroment($$) you could just write "al", then using space bar transform it to "\alpha". This way taking math notes gets so fast if you use repetitive notation.

I was wondering if it is available another similar feature in Overleaf. Thanks for your help

Comment: According to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479104/31283), autocompletion was not a user-customised option, unless it has been changed. However, almost every editor you can install these days has an option to expand snippets; this is either built-in feature or expanded via a plugin. Have a look at the [big list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) of editors that work with LaTeX. You would also need to install a local TeX distribution: TeXLive or MiKTeX, etc. or MaCTeX if you're on MacOS.

Comment: I thought of that but I didn't know many editors and I was using overleaf because its more comfortable. Also I use it in order to avoid packages problems. Thanks for the list and help. I'll check it out.